# TemplateURL based on json-file in routeProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using **Angular 1.2** and i want to define routing based on a json file.

So i am reading a json-file, and based of an attribute, i want to use a different templateUrl.

So lets say:

```
if(jsonfile.option == '2') {TemplateUrl: 'option2.html'};
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "template" with an inline DIV, doing a ng-include to a variable.. something as below:

```
...
template: '<div ng-include="optionTpl"></div>',
...
```

In the route definition & based on the "option" coming in path param, set the "optionTpl" variable to the required URL

```
...
$scope.optionTpl = "option"+jsonfile.option+".html"
...
```